# Slang for US Dollar

Tags: argot

I am wondering if there is any French slang for dollar besides "balle"? I want to talk about American dollar exactly. Not a substitute for franc or euro and not piasse as said in Quebec. Thanks!

Comment: In France, nobody uses American (or Canadian) dollars, so no need to have slang word for it.

Answer (score 3):

One that comes to mind, and that I have both heard people use and encountered in books, is ***dolluche***, coined using the *-iche/-oche/-uche* ending, which belongs to a class of suffixes popularly used to create slang versions of ordinary words. Examples of more common words with such endings are *amerloque* (‘American’, ‘Yank’) and *sourdingue* (‘totally deaf’).

There is also *bifton vert* (*bifton* being slang for banknote and also written *biffeton*), but I have the impression that it is used much less than *dolluche*.